# Include CSS file based on breakpoint

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, breakpoints

We wanted to load certain files based on breakpoints for all devices. Below is a sample what the HTML output we are generating, but are unable to get the files to load based on the `media` attribute in the `<link>` field.

**Question**

How can we load certain files based on a breakpoint?

**What we tried**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="some/path/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 480px)" href="some/path/all-480.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 768px)" href="some/path/all-768.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1200px)" href="some/path/all-1200.css">
  </head>
  <body>
     <p> Some body</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Current Problem**

1. When we open Chrome Dev tools, we noticed that on page load all the files are fetched.

**Expected Results**

1. `some/path/all.css` should be loaded for all breakpoints.
2. `some/path/all-480.css` should only be loaded if the window on load or resize is greater than `480px`
3. `some/path/all-768.css` should only be loaded if the window on load or resize is greater than `768px`
4. `some/path/all-1200.css` should only be loaded if the window on load or resize is greater than `1200px`

Comment: Your code is missing closing parentheses in the media attributes.

Comment: @AngelPolitis sorry, that was a copy and paste error on my part. it is added on the local site i have.

Comment: If you implement this strategy, then the browser will have lengthy 'flashes of unstyled content' (the  unpleasant ['FOUC'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)) while the relevant stylesheet loads, presumably relatively slowly over a mobile network. So: why?

Comment: @DavidThomas it was to minimize the CSS files and only fetch what was needed. It sounds like you are recommending an alternative?